# regex:how to specify and end of the capture

Tags: regex, splunk

lets say I har raw data thats like this

```
  ERROR -- : FluentLogger: Can't convert to msgpack: (blah: blah: balh:.... ):
```

I want to capture

```
FluentLogger: Can't convert to msgpack:
```

currently I have this

```
(?>ERROR -- :)(?<msg1>.*):
```

but the problem with this is that it would capture

```
FluentLogger: Can't convert to msgpack: (blah: blah: balh:.... ):
```

how would I write the regex for that?

Comment: Since you seem to be new here - [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex: `/ERROR -- : ([A-Za-z]+:[\s\w']+):/g`

[Demo and explanation](https://regex101.com/r/khRaM3/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

[`(?<=ERROR -- : ).*msgpack:`](https://regex101.com/r/ar9A3z/1)

Note this is close to your original attempt:

```
(?>ERROR -- :)(?<msg1>.*):
```

but not quite, since you use `?>` for look behind, but it should have been (`?<=`).

Answer (score 0):

One or more 'not :' by ':' use

```
[^:]+:
```

To find the first two of these in a string

```
/[^:]+:[^:]+:/
```

To capture the first two of these after ERROR -- : in a string

```
(?>ERROR -- :)(?[^:]+:[^:]+:)
```